# Notice: Undefined index: name

Tags: php, html, post, xampp, http-post

I just installed XAMPP with PHP 7. I had a script that worked before, but after installing there is an error. I will show an example which is also not working. The problem is in $_POST, I think it can be because of configurations in XAMPP or PHP.

```
<?php 
echo "<form action='check.php' method=\"post\"> 
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" >
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"ok\">
</form>";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){echo $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['name'])) var_dump($_POST['name']);
?>
```

This code doesn't return anything, but if I just add `echo $_POST['name'];` it returns error "Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\XAMPP\php\www\index.php on line 13". How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: try by removing `backslash(\)` not needed actually

Comment: I removed and user 'name' instead \"name\". But nothing changed. @A-2-A

Comment: Why don't you just write the form in pure HTML, then start PHP *after* the closing form tag? Makes for cleaner code. No need to use echo to paste that much HTML, can just exit PHP and go back in after.

Comment: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action='index.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='name' >
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='ok'>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){echo $_POST['name'];}
echo $_POST['name'];
if (isset($_POST['name'])) var_dump($_POST['name']);
?>'      @Qirel the same error.

Comment: In your comment you used `form action='index.php'` but in your code `form action='check.php'`. Your code will work if and only if you will give same page name in`form action`. otherwise you will be redirect to next page and code will not work

Comment: no I know, I just changed the name of PHP file. It is alright. @A-2-A

Comment: @ShamilOmarov YOU FIND THE SOLUTION?

Comment: @A-2-A Actually problem was not in code. All of this happened because I used PHP Storm and the problem was in interpereter I have chosen. Now I just use other editor and everything is allright :)

Answer (score 2):

@hherger I deleted xampp server and installed wampserver with php 5.6. Now it shows another error.

**Deprecated**: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

**Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the code for all **REQUEST_METHOD**s in the same script.
That's ok, but then you have to differentiate how you react:

- either send out the form for the user to fill out and transmit,
- or interprete the data transmitted by the form.

Try this code adopted from yours:

```
<?php
    // Check if the form has been transmitted or not
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        // A form was transmitted
        if (isset($_POST['name'])) var_dump($_POST['name']);
    } else {
        // Send the form out so the user can transmit it
        echo "<form action='check.php' method=\"post\"> 
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" >
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"ok\">
</form>";
    }
?>
```